# Setting PATH variable that the value contains HOME variable with user systemd does not work

Tags: linux, systemd

Here is the content of `~/.config/environment.d/bin.conf`:

```
PATH=${HOME}/.bin:${PATH}
```

This does not work. However, if it is a simple configuration without other variables embedded in the value it will work. e.g.:

```
EDITOR=vim
```

Here is the resulted `PATH`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:PATH_TO_HOME/.local/share/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Comment: What would you expect user systemd's home directory to be?  Most services intentionally don't have a home directory.  Perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It just my guess due to if systemd know where to find per-user configurations that mean `HOME` should be pointed to the right directory.

Comment: Thats the thing.. services don't typically have per user configurations.  When they need something like that, they use /etc/.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas There is another mode of systemd to start a new instance for each user when they are logged in. I don't know what is the official name for it. You can see here for some details about it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User